# Thumbnail grid with expanding with Ajax e PHP

Tags: php, ajax, grid

Hello I am trying to add a cool feature in this script

> http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

And I would to ask for your help because I've done several attempts and not find a solution.

I would like to know how do I implement loading dynamic content via ajax and php so that each click one of the images of the grid, I automatically load the content in this html href within the expanded yet "og-expander" in grid.js file, I changed some lines:

within the function:

```
create: function () {
```

I added this:

```
previewEl = $ $ ('<div class="og-expander"> </ div>') load ('test.html')..;
```

So that I have the contents of an external loaded html inside the div, plus this option is valid for all would like to know how to capture the href of each element and load the external html corresponding to the item and tabém display a status of Loading, who appreciate being able to collaborate as if one could implement this functionality this script will be complete.

Comment: Could you please paste the code you have tried?